# Microcontroller timer overflow

Tags: timer, formula, microcontroller, atmega

I'm wondering what could be the formula to calculate (TIMER0 in this case) timer so that the overflow happens ~1 time per millisecond.

currently the clock is set to 1MHz and predivider is 128 and counting is from 130 to 255 clock cycles.

I'm using Atmega128 microcontroller if it helps in any way

I tried to use the formula where I divide the set clock with predivider multiplied by 256, but it didn't match the expected result

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, providing a [mre] that shows how you initialize the timer. AFAIK the timer0 cannot count repeatedly from 130 to 255 by itself.

Answer (score 2):

In the ATMega128, the TIMER0 peripheral increments the TCNT0 register on every clock cycle, and compares its value to the contents of the OCR0 register. The behaviour on timer compare match can be configured to either trigger an interrupt, or toggle a pin. The timer can also be set to Clear Timer on Compare (CTC) mode to automatically restart the count once a compare match is made.

To have something happen every 1 ms with a 1 MHz clock, you need to find a combination of prescaler setting and OCR0 value that is reached every 1 ms. You then need to configure the timer to trigger the interrupt on compare match, and put your every-1-millisecond code in the interrupt subroutine.

With a 1 MHz clock, the only workable combination of prescaler and OCR0 is a prescaler of 8 and an OCR0 of 124. In other words, you have a 1 us clock period, and need to count (124 + 1) * 8 = 1000 clocks per ms.

Note that we use one less than the expected value of 125: according to the datasheet,

> A match will set the output compare flag (OCF0) at the next timer clock cycle.

In other words, a match after 124 clocks triggers the interrupt one clock cycle after.

Since in your code you have set the prescaler to 128, and are counting to 125, your interrupts as described in your question will actually trigger every 16 ms.

C-style pseudocode to do this:

```c
ISR(TIMER0_VECTOR){
  // an Interrupt Sub-Routine for your code that has to run every 1 ms
}

void setup() {
  CRITICAL_SECTION_ENTER(); // turn off interrupts
  TCCR0 = 0b00001010; // sets CTC mode, prescaler=8
  TCNT0 = 0; // zeroes the counter
  OCR0 = 125 - 1;
  TIMSK |= 0b00000010; // enables Interrupt-On-Compare for Timer 0
                       // NOTE the |= as this register controls
                       // all three timers!!
  CRITICAL_SECTION_LEAVE(); // turn interrupts back on
}

void loop() {
  // your main code here
}
```

To address a different part of your question:

> counting is from 130 to 255 clock cycles

you can, in theory, use the overflow interrupt instead of the CTC interrupt, and then write 130 into the TCNT0 count register as part of your overflow interrupt subroutine, but setting TCNT0 isn't instantaneous and your timer would drift by a few clock cycles every ms. I recommend the standard way of counting from 0 to 125, rather than from 130 to 255.